# How does one compare two linked lists nodes in Java?

Tags: java, list, conditional-statements, selection

I am trying to write a searching algorithm to check one node in a linked integer list vs another node in that same list.

I think there seems to be a problem with the IF statement (data is in the list):

```
   LinkedList<Integer> listScore = new LinkedList<Integer>();
   int temp = 0;
   String temp2 = "";
   boolean flag = true;
   while (flag){
   flag = false;
   for (int j = 0; j < linebr; j++){
     if (listScore(j) < listScore(j+1)){
        System.out.println("Testing");
     }
}
```

I did originally try listScore[j] but I think there is something wrong with the way I have written it. Any help or explanation as to why it doesent work would be Greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The answer is in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  By the way, if one of your main needs is to retrieve the `j`'th item of a list, _do not use LinkedList_.  This is because to get the `j`'th item, it has to start from the head of the list and step through `j+1` nodes, which slows things down a lot.  `ArrayList` is a much better choice for this use.

Comment: I did worry about that, but I feel I have no choice because I have an end of term assignment and we had to incorporate linkedlists somewhere in the game (battleships for me) and a score system was the only way I thought as it dynamic. Would a binary search be decent?

Comment: First off: without a precise description of the problem, we have to search for the problem ourselves first, which is quite counterproductive, so please add it to the question. And in fact you have multiple problem, you just don't know yet. I'd recommend you read [an introduction to collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/)

Comment: Will do Paul, in future I will be more succinct, and I'll take a read shortly!

Comment: Binary search on a linked list is awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `listscore(j)` and `listscore(j+1)`, what you need to get values inside `LinkedLists` is `.get()`. So you should be using `listscore.get(j)` and `listscore.get(j+1)`.

Comment: You're a star! Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help you! @Samuelf80 Could you please press the tick to mark the answer as correct! :D

Comment: yeah I tried to but I had to wait some time first and I totally forgot!